# Replacing SQL replication

Tags: sql-server, merge, transactional-replication

We are looking to replace SQL SERVER replication.

Today we've got several version on SQL installations because SQL replication does not support working with different SQL versions (2005 and 2008 for example), so instead of having several installation of SQL version (2005,2008,2012 etc...), we are looking install a single version on the server (let's say 2014) and using this version to replicate between all our clients (2005+).

Today we are using transnational and merge replication at the same time for each database.

I would like to know:

- Is there a way to make different version replicate with each other?
- Is there and good tool that can replace that replication?

Comment: Not sure, what do you mean, replication is possible between different versions, see http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/71500/44324

Comment: Does it mean that both ends are setup as publisher/distributor (one for merge replication and one for transactional replication)? Is that what you call 2way replication?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2014 supports replication with SQL Server 2008 and on. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms143550(v=sql.120).aspx
So if you use SQL Server 2012 as backend, SQL Server 2005, 2008 and 2012 clients are supported.

Comment: I know that 2014 support replication of 2008,
but when your replicating 2way then the 2008/5 dose not support the 2014.

Answer (score 0):

We are using transnactional replication between 2012 and 2016 and 2014 and 2016.  For us the trick was to create a publisher on the older version and a pull subscription on the newer version.  The only other thing to watch out for is you need to manage the relationship in SSMS using the older server as trying to go to properties from the 2016 box will throw an error.

I saw something about changing data types or another server setting that would eliminate the errors so it might be worth looking around.